# Blazor WebAssembly - trackBy equivalent

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor, blazor

I'm working on performance comparison between Angular and Blazor for my thesis. I want to do it base on this open source framework: https://github.com/krausest/js-framework-benchmark. To do it I need to write my own implementation of test app in Blazor. I did it, but I have one problem. Angular has trackBy keyword (example below) that enable to change only one row of collection in DOM when model changes. Without this keyword every model change require rebuild of whole table (https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf#ngForTrackBy). Is there any equivalent in Blazor?

```
        <tr [class.danger]="item.id === selected" *ngFor="let item of data; trackBy: itemById">
            <td class="col-md-1">{{item.id}}</td>
            <td class="col-md-4">
                <a href="#" (click)="select(item, $event)">{{item.label}}</a>
            </td>
            <td class="col-md-1"><a href="#" (click)="delete(item, $event)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span></a></td>
            <td class="col-md-6"></td>
        </tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the [`@key` directive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#use-key-to-control-the-preservation-of-elements-and-components):

```cs
@foreach (var todos in todoLists) {
    <TodoListCard @key=@todos.Id Todos=@todos />
}
```

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#use-key-to-control-the-preservation-of-elements-and-components):

> When rendering a list of elements or components and the elements or components subsequently change, Blazor's diffing algorithm must decide which of the previous elements or components can be retained and how model objects should map to them. Normally, this process is automatic and can be ignored, but there are cases where you may want to control the process.
>
> The mapping process can be controlled with the @key directive attribute. @key causes the diffing algorithm to guarantee preservation of elements or components based on the key's value.